# Karma delivers wrong code coverage report

Tags: angular, jasmine, code-coverage, karma-runner, istanbul

I am struggling a bit trying to generate an authentic coverage report for an application I am testing.
**Method I am trying to test:**

[image: Method I am trying to test.]

**The test that runs perfectly:**
[image]

**And my karma.conf.js:**

```html
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-firefox-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      // require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    // coverageIstanbulReporter: {
    //   dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './frontend/base/src/app'),
    //   reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
    //   fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    // },
    coverageReporter: {
      type : 'html',
      dir : 'coverage/'
    },
    preprocessors: {
      'src/app/*.ts': ['coverage']
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'coverage'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: [],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test coverage is Ok. The `this.router.events` never fires any event after subscription, so the test never goes through the pipe and so the lines 43-47 are not executed. Check also the expectations in your test. From the code you provided it looks like `defaultMachine === undefined`.

Comment: Is there a way to force the router to fire an event? Also, the data provided from the customer only includes 1 machine, and since that machine is not set as the default machine, defaultmachine is undefined by default.